# Error installing bazel for tensorflow: command not found

Tags: cmd, terminal, tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to use bazel to run retrain Inception's Final Layer for New Categories in Tensorflow.

I have limited knowledge of anything other than jupyter notebooks, so terminal work = copying and pasting.

I installed bazel via brew. So it's there somewhere.

When I run:

```
bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain
```

I recieve the error:

```
-bash: bazel: command not found
```

So I tried this too:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

But nothing happened. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
$ brew info bazel
```

This should print a path to wherever it installed Bazel.  You can either use it from there (`/usr/local/Cellar/bazel/0.3.1/bin/bazel build tensorflow/and/so/on`) or create a symlink to somewhere on your PATH, e.g.,

```
$ mkdir $HOME/bin
$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/bazel/0.3.1/bin/bazel $HOME/bin/bazel
```

Then it should work with the first command you tried.

(Verify that bazel actually *is* at `/usr/local/Cellar/bazel/0.3.1/bin/bazel`, that's just a guess.)

Comment: Could you please eventually translate those commands in Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have to check whether you already have `bazel` installed. `which bazel` can do the trick. If `bazel` is not installed on your machine. Try to follow guide in this page to install bazel. https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/install-ubuntu.html

Comment: Hello @zhexuany, the link encounter 404 error. May I know any document to install bazel in linux aarch64 architecture?